Difference between DWT based reconstruction and MRA components
I recently learnt basics of wavelet transform and multi-resolution analysis. I'm analyzing a signal with 14,000 data points. I wish to extract low-frequency features of this signal, and for that, I'm using the PyWavelets library in Python.
I extracted the low-frequency features using two methods.

Computed DWT of the signal with 'coif1' wavelet and level = 5. Reconstructed signal only using the approximate coefficient and detailed coefficient 5.
Used the built-in pywt.mra with the same wavelet and levels.


In the attached figure, you can see that to the eye, the signal looks strikingly similar. However, the magnitude of peaks is different (and is not a constant scaling factor). Furthermore, if I look at the PDF of these two low frequency signals, they too look different near the peak (difference which is of significance).
Since I'm using same number of levels and wavelets in both the methods, what explains the difference?
